# Problem with december in function to calculate week-end Js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I use a function to calculate if the day is a week-end or no, the function work, but not for december. What is wrong?

```
 weekEnd: function(date) {
      // know if week or week-end
      var date1 = new Date(date);
      var day = date1.getDay();
      var resultat = 1;

      if (day === 6 || day === 0) {
        resultat = 0;
      }
      return resultat;
    },
```

Comment: How did you test it against december?

Comment: like other month, i call the function with the date : v-if="weekEnd(date)"

Comment: The code function should work... Maybe the problem is how you are calling it, can you share?

Comment: <td style="min-width: 40px" v-for="(date,index1) of dates" v-bind:key="index1">
                    <!-- Boucle for sur la date pour chaque utilisateur -->
                    <form v-if="weekEnd(date)">
                      <select

Comment: What's the content of `dates` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't reproduce the steps as it works for me. But instead of using 0 or 1, you can use boolean values true or false.

Maybe if you're having this issue, it's because the date format is the wrong one.

It looks like you're French (according to your comment) and maybe your **Date object is set to use MM-DD-YYYY** date format instead of our french format being DD-MM-YYYY

Here is my code and it works for me, even in december :

```js
const isWeekend = (date) => {
    const day = new Date(date).getDay()
    return ( day == 6 || day == 0)
}

// 12-15-2019 --> Sunday 15th December 2019
console.log(isWeekend('12-15-2019')) // returns true
```

Comment: Ton code devrait marcher, tu entres bien la date sous le format Mois/Jour/Année ?